# Formatting Time Durations in Excel, Unnecessary zeros

Tags: excel, formatting

I would like to display minutes and hours in a readable style

Currently, I am using the format:

```
hh"h" mm"m"
```

So:

- 1 minute, i.e. TIME(0,1,0), will show as 00h 01m
- 1 hour, i.e. TIME(1,0,0), will show as 01h 00m
- 1 hour 1 minute, i.e. TIME(1,1,0), will show as 01h 01m

I would like to remove unnecessary zero's

- 1m
- 1h
- 1h 1m

I am currently formatting the cell externally with the HOUR() and MINUTE() functions, as such:

```
IF(HOUR(A1)>0," "&HOUR(A1)&"h","")&IF(MINUTE(A1)>0," "&MINUTE(A1)&"m","")

CELL A1 = TIME(0,1,0)

DISPLAY: 1m

CELL A1 = TIME(1,0,0)

DISPLAY: 1h

CELL A1 = TIME(1,1,0)

DISPLAY: 1h 1m
```

I want to skip this step and do it directly with formatting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve most of that by using the following custom format

`[>0.041666]h"h" m"m";[m]"m"`

`0.041666` is = 1 hour (or very slightly under) so that shows the hours only when it's on 1 hour or over and by using `h` and `m` rather than `hh` and `mm` you lose the leading zeroes.

The only thing it doesn't do is hide zero minutes so 1 hour exactly will display 1h 0m. You could possibly use **conditional formatting** to get that exactly right, assuming Excel 2007 or later

Comment: I am using Sheets on Google Drive

Comment: How can I hide the zero in "2h 0m" using conditional formatting?